# Is it legal and ethical to reverse engineer software to port it to another system?

Tags: legal, ethics, porting

I love gaming, I love games that allow modding and I love linux. But the fact that most games right now are targeted for windows (consoles aside), most mods and modding tools are also targeted for windows. There is a certain modder called Boris Vorontsov that makes a famous visual overhaul mod series called [ENB](http://enbseries.enbdev.com/).

What he does (or I think he does) is he enhances or changes the behavior of classes defined in the `d3d9.dll` library. Needless to say it almost never works under wine.

Recently I have asked him if he would ever release his version of the library under some open license, and [he said "no"](http://enbseries.enbdev.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=1216). Now that I think of it, even if he did release his code, he would have surely faced some legal problems.

Now there is my question. Is it legal and ethical to reverse engineer his version of the library to adapt the wine's open source version of `d3d9.dll` to be able to run his mods?

Comment: Not worth an answer, but the word *Copyright* comes to mind...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a question of legalities (off topic) and ethics (primarily opinion).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Legal? -> ask a lawyer. Anyway, this depends strongly on the country you distribute your adaptation.

Ethical? -> ask the authors. All of them. Some may see this as a tribute, others as a robbery.

Comment: I guess you're right. I think I'm being confused by the nature of the software I'm looking at. I'm pretty sure it's a copyright infringement to use Direct3D libraries this way, but nevertheless, it's a huge amount of work.

Comment: If you need to do so in order to use a work you lawfully possess, I don't see any ethical problem. It's not robbery to use a work you lawfully possess.